# Send JSON from a slash command using PHP

Tags: php, json, slack

I have created a slash command for Slack and I need to send JSON data to Slack. This is the code I am using but the response is treated as plain text by Slack.

```
$data = "payload=" . json_encode(array(
                    "content-type"  =>  "application/json",
                    "text"          =>  "a message",
                    "response_type" =>  "ephemeral",
                    "username"      =>  "user",
                    "icon_emoji"    =>  ":icon:"                
        ),JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

echo $data;
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe you missed proper json format?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I wasn't building my JSON file according to SLACK conventions.
It should not have the payload parameter which is only used for incoming web hooks. 
The PHP page should include this line:
`header('Content-Type: application/json');`

The slash command response should be built as follows:

```
$data = json_encode(array(
                "content-type"  =>  "application/json",
                "text"          =>  "a message",
                "response_type" =>  "ephemeral",
                "username"      =>  "user",
                "icon_emoji"    =>  ":icon:"                
    ),JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

echo $data;